# Getting ValueError while training facenet

Tags: python, image, opencv, machine-learning, facenet

Im trying this code https://github.com/arsfutura/face-recognition , but While running `sh tasks/train.sh images/` Im getting valueerror as :-

```
images/rah/ra.jpg
/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/facenet_pytorch/models/utils/detect_face.py:146: UserWarning: This overload of nonzero is deprecated:
nonzero()
Consider using one of the following signatures instead:
nonzero(*, bool as_tuple) (Triggered internally at ../torch/csrc/utils/python_arg_parser.cpp:882.)
bb = mask.nonzero().float().flip(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"main", mod_spec)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/home/pi/face-recognition/training/train.py", line 99, in
main()
File "/home/pi/face-recognition/training/train.py", line 84, in main
embeddings, labels, class_to_idx = load_data(args, features_extractor)
File "/home/pi/face-recognition/training/train.py", line 61, in load_data
embeddings, labels = dataset_to_embeddings(dataset, features_extractor)
File "/home/pi/face-recognition/training/train.py", line 41, in dataset_to_embeddings
_, embedding = features_extractor(transform(Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB')))
File "/home/pi/face-recognition/face_recognition/face_features_extractor.py", line 26, in call
return self.extract_features(img)
File "/home/pi/face-recognition/face_recognition/face_features_extractor.py", line 15, in extract_features
bbs, _ = self.aligner.detect(img)
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/facenet_pytorch/models/mtcnn.py", line 308, in detect
self.device
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/facenet_pytorch/models/utils/detect_face.py", line 66, in detect_face
tmp[(dy[k] - 1):edy[k], (dx[k] - 1):edx[k], :] = img[(y[k] - 1):ey[k], (x[k] - 1):ex[k], :]
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0,1364,3) into shape (0,0,3)
```

I even tried hardcoding `tmp = np.zeros((0,1364, 3))` at line 65 in detect_face.py just to test, but no luck.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use facenet within deepface? You just pass the exact image paths as pair and it builds a face recognition pipeline. I mean that verify function handles face detection and alignment in the background.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
obj = DeepFace.verify("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", model_name = 'Facenet')
print(obj["verified"])
```

Or you can find an identity in a data base similarly. Here, you are expected to store facial images with .jpg or .png extention in a folder and pass it to database path.

```
df = DeepFace.find("img1.jpg", db_path="C:/my_db", model_name = 'Facenet')
print(df.head())
```